# What would the received push schema would look like on IOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, kinvey

We are using kinvey business logic to push notification on postSave:
Here is what it look like if sent from engagements:

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": "Hello World",
    "sound": "default"
},

}
```

Comment: For better clarification about notification see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

Comment: but what will the payload schemas be when send by kinvey

Comment: Sorry Gorel,I'am not aware of  **kinvey**.If i found something i'll let you know.

Comment: thanks for your help @Gokul

Answer (score 2):

The `aps` structure is passed as a nested object on the `userInfo` object that is available in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` appDelegate method. You can use it with something like this in Swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification   userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary,
    let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
        // do something with 'alert'
```

(code snippet from http://www.intertech.com/Blog/push-notifications-tutorial-for-ios-9/)

Comment: i already have all that in place, i just want to know how the json is if triggered from kinvey onPostSave which include a collection object

Comment: do you mean the json inside the Kinvey Business Logic layer? on the iOS side, there is no json, just NSDictonaries.